# $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ has no unramified extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

It is a classical result that every extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ is ramified. Put differently: there are no unramified extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$. The classical proof follows from the following two statements:

> (a) The only number field having discriminant $1$ is $\mathbb{Q}$ itself.
>
> (b) A prime number $p$ ramifies in a number field $K$ if and only if it is a divisor of the discriminant $\Delta_K$.

Is it possible to argue for something similar for $\mathbb{Q}(i)$? The goal of my question is to construct an example of a Hilbert Class Field without appealing (yet) to Artin Reciprocity.

> Using Artin Reciprocity, one has that $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q}) \cong Cl(\mathbb{Q})$, where $L$ is the Hilbert Class Field of $K=\mathbb{Q}$. Now, because $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID, the class group becomes trivial, and we have that $L=\mathbb{Q}$. Since $L$ is by definition the maximal unramified abelian extension of $K=\mathbb{Q}$, this implies that there are no unramified extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$. Repeating the argument (and observing that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a PID), one deduces that the Hilbert Class Field of $K=\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is $L=\mathbb{Q}(i)$. But this just means that $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ has no unramified extensions.

However, I would like to have a proof from scratch which argues that $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ has no unramified extensions.

EDIT: My question seems related to this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26491/is-there-a-ring-of-integers-except-for-z-such-that-every-extension-of-it-is-ram) but I am having trouble following the argument there.

Comment: Your question is to prove the statement or to construct a Hilbert-class field without invoking to Artin reciprocity?

Comment: My main interest is to prove the statement that $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ has no unramified extensions. I assumed this was the most simple example of constructing a HCF without appealing to Artin Reciprocity. If someone happens to be interested in this latter issue, I can always start a new post for that.

Comment: What don't you follow about KConrad's argument? It seems about as simple as you can get. As I'm sure you know, while showing that $\mathbb{Q}$ admits no unramified extensions is "elementary" (at least compared to class field theory) it is extremely sophisticated.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to do this for $\mathbb Q(i)$, and this precisely what
is done in the linked MO question.

Note also that CFT describes *abelian* everywhere unramified extensions.
The statement about having *no* everywhere unramified extensions is
stronger.